# Microsoft OneNote Graph API page creation with background

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, microsoft-graph-onenote

I am using the Microsoft one-note graph API for creating pages according to their demand in HTML.
Is there any possibility to create a page with a background image? Because I would like to use it as the background of a fillable form.
I should be filled by handwriting with a pen on a tablet in the OneNote app.

Or are there any other, better approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely create pages - see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/section-post-pages?view=graph-rest-1.0).

The background can be an image or pdf.
 I however much prefer to use a template page that you create yourself (directly in one note) and copy using [page: copyToSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/page-copytosection?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). This allows you to use the added functionality of onenote such as ruled pages, setting images as backgrounds, etc.